# WebRTC, getDisplayMedia() does not capture sound from the remote stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc, webapi, peerjs

I have a web application of my own, which is based on the peerjs library (It is a video conference).

I'm trying to make a recording with 'MediaRecorder', but I'm facing a very unpleasant case.

The code for capturing my desktop stream is the following:

```
let chooseScreen = document.querySelector('.chooseScreenBtn')
chooseScreen.onclick = async () => {
    let desktopStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video:true, audio: true });
}
```

I then successfully apply my received **desktopStream** to **videoElement** in DOM:

```
const videoElement = doc.querySelector('.videoElement')
  videoElement.srcObject = desktopStream 
  videoElement.muted = false;
  videoElement.onloadedmetadata = ()=>{videoElement.play();}
```

For example, I get **desktopStream** on the page with an active conference where everyone hears and sees each other.

To check the video and audio in **desktopStream**  I play some video on the video player on the desktop.
I can hear any audio from my desktop but audio from any participant cannot be heard.
Of course, when I put the desktopStream in MediaRecorder I get a video file with no sound from anyone except my desktop. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like restrictOwnAudio defaults to true. Try setting it to false on your constraints object as an audio property.

Reference: https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#dfn-restrictownaudio.

Comment: I did it as you advice `desktopStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video:true,audio: {restrictOwnAudio: false,}`, but nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: It happens when I get desktopStream on the same page with conference, When I take out this functionality to another page, it works fine.

Comment: @AndrewMedvedev were you able to resolve it? i am facing similar issue

Comment: Briefly, I decided to merge all audio tracks from remote users with AudioContext including the own audio track. Also, I take the audio track from every users who connect and bind it with MediaStream too. As a result I always have the actual audio from all users. This topic is about how it to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317945/adding-an-audiotrack-while-the-mediarecorder-is-in-state-recording    there is a function to merge some audio tracks https://jsfiddle.net/onadmin/qvtd5cwo/21/

Answer (score 4):

Chrome's `MediaRecorder` API can only output one `track`.
The `createMediaStreamSource` can take streams from desktop audio and microphone, by connecting both together into one object created by `createMediaStreamDestination` it gives you the ability to pipe this one stream into the `MediaRecorder` API.

```
const mergeAudioStreams = (desktopStream, voiceStream) => {
    const context = new AudioContext();

    // Create a couple of sources
    const source1 = context.createMediaStreamSource(desktopStream);
    const source2 = context.createMediaStreamSource(voiceStream);
    const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

    const desktopGain = context.createGain();
    const voiceGain = context.createGain();

    desktopGain.gain.value = 0.7;
    voiceGain.gain.value = 0.7;

    source1.connect(desktopGain).connect(destination);
    // Connect source2
    source2.connect(voiceGain).connect(destination);

    return destination.stream.getAudioTracks();
};
```

It is also possible to use two or more audio inputs + video input.

```
window.onload = () => {
    const warningEl = document.getElementById('warning');
    const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');
    const captureBtn = document.getElementById('captureBtn');
    const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
    const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
    const download = document.getElementById('download');
    const audioToggle = document.getElementById('audioToggle');
    const micAudioToggle = document.getElementById('micAudioToggle');
    
    if('getDisplayMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) warningEl.style.display = 'none';

    let blobs;
    let blob;
    let rec;
    let stream;
    let voiceStream;
    let desktopStream;
    
    const mergeAudioStreams = (desktopStream, voiceStream) => {
        const context = new AudioContext();
        const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        let hasDesktop = false;
        let hasVoice = false;
        if (desktopStream && desktopStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
        // If you don't want to share Audio from the desktop it should still work with just the voice.
        const source1 = context.createMediaStreamSource(desktopStream);
        const desktopGain = context.createGain();
        desktopGain.gain.value = 0.7;
        source1.connect(desktopGain).connect(destination);
        hasDesktop = true;
        }
        
        if (voiceStream && voiceStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
        const source2 = context.createMediaStreamSource(voiceStream);
        const voiceGain = context.createGain();
        voiceGain.gain.value = 0.7;
        source2.connect(voiceGain).connect(destination);
        hasVoice = true;
        }
        
        return (hasDesktop || hasVoice) ? destination.stream.getAudioTracks() : [];
    };

    captureBtn.onclick = async () => {
        download.style.display = 'none';
        const audio = audioToggle.checked || false;
        const mic = micAudioToggle.checked || false;
        
        desktopStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video:true, audio: audio });
        
        if (mic === true) {
        voiceStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: mic });
        }
    
        const tracks = [
        ...desktopStream.getVideoTracks(), 
        ...mergeAudioStreams(desktopStream, voiceStream)
        ];
        
        console.log('Tracks to add to stream', tracks);
        stream = new MediaStream(tracks);
        console.log('Stream', stream)
        videoElement.srcObject = stream;
        videoElement.muted = true;
        
        blobs = [];
    
        rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp8,opus'});
        rec.ondataavailable = (e) => blobs.push(e.data);
        rec.onstop = async () => {
        
        blob = new Blob(blobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        download.href = url;
        download.download = 'test.webm';
        download.style.display = 'block';
        };
        startBtn.disabled = false;
        captureBtn.disabled = true;
        audioToggle.disabled = true;
        micAudioToggle.disabled = true;
    };

    startBtn.onclick = () => {
        startBtn.disabled = true;
        stopBtn.disabled = false;
        rec.start();
    };

    stopBtn.onclick = () => {
        captureBtn.disabled = false;
        audioToggle.disabled = false;
        micAudioToggle.disabled = false;
        startBtn.disabled = true;
        stopBtn.disabled = true;
        
        rec.stop();
        
        stream.getTracks().forEach(s=>s.stop())
        videoElement.srcObject = null
        stream = null;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Audio capture with `getDisplayMedia` is only fully supported with Chrome for Windows.  Other platforms have a number of limitations:

- there is no support for audio capture at all under Firefox or Safari;
- on Chrome/Chromium for Linux and Mac OS, only the audio of a Chrome/Chromium tab can be captured, not the audio of a non-browser application window.

Comment: I capture audio with getDisplayMedia  under lastest version of Chrome browser and I dont understand why i cannot capture both the desktop`s audio and the audio from conference tab. The sound from conference tab is ignored, but the other sound is not. I repeat It again, this happens when I get desktopStream on the same page with conference, when I take this functionality out  to another page, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

`const displayMediaOptions = {audio: { echoCancellation: false }};`

This will capture your conference tab too.